# How to convert Array of Struct to List Realm?

Tags: swift, realm

i want to convert Array from struct to List Realm .

```
static func mapGenreResponsetoGenreEntity( input genre: [GenreModel]) -> List {
    var list = List<GenreEntity>()
    
    return  genre.map { result in
        let newGenre =  GenreEntity()
        newGenre.gamesCount = result.gamesCount ?? 0
        newGenre.id = result.id ?? 0
        newGenre.imageBackground = result.imageBackground ?? "Unknown"
        newGenre.name = result.name ?? "Unknown"
        newGenre.slug = result.slug ?? "Unknown"
  
        list.append(newGenre)
  
        return list
    }
}
```

and the genre is

```
struct GenreModel: Codable {
  let gamesCount : Int?
  let id : Int?
  let imageBackground : String?
  let name : String?
  let slug : String?
}
```

How can i convert from array genre (Struct) to List realm which is GenreEntity ?

Comment: Please don’t include images or links in your questions. Include code and structures as text so we can use them in answers with copy/paste. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Images and links are not searchable so they may not be of use to future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should just be a matter of adding the new GenreEntity objects to an array and then return the entire array once done.

This should do it

```
func convertToList(genreArray: [GenreClass]) -> List<GenreEntityRealmModel> {
    let genreEntityList = List<GenreEntityRealmModel>()
    genreArray.forEach { model in
        let genreEntity = GenreEntity()
        genreEntity.gamesCount = model.gamesCount
        genreEntityList.append(genreEntity)
    }
    return genreEntityList
}
```

Comment: @amaulana Glad to help. I also formatted the code in your question to make it readable. There are formatting tools in the editor when asking questions - the brackets {} that format the code can really help keep the code lined up.

Comment: @amaulana also a quick trick is to do `Ctrl` + `i`. This re-indents you code.

Comment: Could you please say how can I convert List<Int> to [Int]? Tried many answers from SO but still can't find solution :(

Comment: @Abrcd18 You probably don't want to don't need to do that. Leaving realm objects as realm objects has some benefits over casting them to a swift array. May I ask why you want/need to do that? You can just do this `Array(your realm list)` but again, that may not be the best choice depending on the use case.

Comment: I'm doing the same task as the author of question. I want to write movies to Realm and assign every property of Movies to CachedMovies and then add that object to Realm, but I can't only assign genreID (List<Int>) property to genreID ([Int]). 

func saveMovies(movies:[Movies]) {
    do {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try realm.write {
        movies.forEach { (movie) in
            let movieRealm = CachedMovies()
            movieRealm.id = movie.id ?? 0
            movieRealm.title = movie.title ?? ""
            movieRealm.genreIDs = movie.genreIDs ?? []

Comment: Tried to cast as you suggested but array comes empty 

 var newArr = Array(movieRealm.genreIDs)
 newArr = movie.genreIDs ?? []

Comment: @Abrcd18 It's really hard to diagnose issues within comments. This code `Array(your realm list)` works, 100% of the time and casts a Realm List to an array. However, there are a LOT of downfalls to doing that. It would be best to create a question with a minimal example of the difficulty and an an explanation of what you're trying to do. Do that, link it here and we'll take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67380208/how-to-cast-realm-list-to-an-array could you please look at the question