# How to convert an array to List in Realm?

Tags: swift, realm

I have a problem with converting Realm type **List < Int>** array to Int array **[Int]** when writing jsonData to Realm.

```
 struct Movies: Codable {
        let genreIDs: [Int]?
 }

 class CachedMovies: Object {
      let genreIDs: List<Int>?
 }

 func saveMovies(movies:[Movies]) {
    do {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try realm.write {
        movies.forEach { (movie) in
            let movieRealm = CachedMovies()
            movieRealm.id = movie.id ?? 0
            movieRealm.title = movie.title ?? ""
            movieRealm.genreIDs = movie.genreIDs ?? [] // here's error: Cannot assign value of type '[Int]?' to type 'List<Int>?'
            realm.add(movieRealm, update: .modified)
        }
        }
    }
```

I tried this but array comes empty

```
var newArr = Array(movieRealm.genreIDs)
newArr = movie.genreIDs ?? []
```

I also tried to change List type to Results and convert Results to Int by using this extension but it's not working.

```
extension Results {
     func toArray<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
     return compactMap { $0 as ? T }
     }
    }
```

Could you please help me how can I assign arrays correctly?

Comment: can you show me the result so i might help you.

Comment: what result do you mean?

Comment: kind of data are you trying to convert.

Comment: thanks for trying me to help, task is solved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that your problem is not about converting `List` to array, but rather converting an array to `List`. You already know how to do the former: `Array(someList)`, but since you are assigning an array (`movie.genreIDs ?? []`) to a `List` property (`movieRealm.genreIDs`), you need to convert an array to a `List`.

But wait! `movieRealm.genreIDs` is a `let` constant, so you can't assign to it anyway. Your real problem is that you haven't declared the `genreIDs` property correctly.

If you follow the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/data-types/supported-property-types/) on how to declare a property of a `List` type:

```
class CachedMovies: Object {
     // genreIDs should not be optional
     let genreIDs = List<Int>()
}
```

You'll see that you don't need to convert arrays to `List`. You can just add the contents of the array to the `List`, since the list is not nil:

```
movieRealm.genreIDs.append(objectsIn: move.genreIDs ?? [])
```

Note that if you actually want an *optional* list property (a property which can be nil, empty, or have elements), Realm doesn't support that.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation! I didn't think about to append int array to List, and just assigned as the other properties. Now I will know how to work with List :)

Answer (score 2):

BTW If your purpose is actually to convert an array to a Realm List:

```swift
let yourList = List()
yourList.append(objectsIn: /* your array here */)
```

Comment: This code`let yourList = List()` is not valid as it's a Generic which cannot be inferred. It would need to be this: `let myList = List<SomeRealmObject>()`

Answer (score 0):

```swift
let swiftList = [Date(), Date(), Date()]
let realmList = List<Date>()
realmlist.append(objectsIn: swiftList)
```

Explicit data type need to be used when initiating the Realm List object.